# WKWebView white-screen after loading content

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, ios10, wkwebview

We have a native app that embeds WKWebView to display content. It is used to display a series of interactive activities which are drawn in a canvas element.

After spending some time in the app, and loading a number of resources, we experience a white screen, indicating that the process has crashed [(crashlog here)](https://gist.github.com/thebarge/c76fa2beaca907aab7d2c82e3a09943c). We’ve made a number of changes to our app to try and help reduce the heap size, to no avail.

The crash is repeatable and always happens at the exact same time within the app. The app performs better in iOS 9 -- this only happens at this time in iOS 10, including the 10.1 beta (14B55c).

Does this crash log look familiar to anyone? Here's the topline:

`Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xfffffff0
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0`

Thank you!

Comment: I have noticed an increase in crashes coming from WebViews in iOS10. Could possibly be a bug, but it's difficult to isolate

Comment: Here's a [link to the corresponding discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65711) on the Apple Developer Forums in case there are any updates there.